# How can I handle Windows "C:" URIs on a next js 12 app?

Tags: windows, webpack, next.js, url-scheme

I have a current script on my next js 12 app to "**npm run buils && next export**" that should create static files for c=some widgetized versions on my pages.

When I'm running the command I'm getting the following error:

"**" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled schema)
Webpack supports 'data:' and 'file:' URIs by default
You may need an additional plugin to handle 'c:' URIs.**"

How can I fix this issue?
Anyway I can configure some next.config.js file to solve this error?

Comment: Could you use the [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton!
Don't know... DO you know by chance how can use it? insode my next.config file? maybe?

Comment: Where you have `C:\some\path\file.ext`, use `file:///C:/some/file/path.ext`.